# get_query_var returning nothing or 0?

Tags: php, wordpress, woothemes

Im using canvas template for my website, and I have also created my customized search in search.php

The search works fine till I have to paginate the results. When showing the first page, the url:
http://myurl.com/search/?location=0&type=0&bedrooms=empty&bathrooms=empty&minprice=empty&maxprice=empty&ref=&submit=Search

works great. Then at the bottom of the page (search.php), I call

```
woo_pagination();
```

And it shows me the number of pages and next buttons, so far so good, but when I click on next, the url is:
http://myurl.com/search/page/3/?location=0&type=0&bedrooms=empty&bathrooms=empty&minprice=empty&maxprice=empty&ref&submit=Search

And I get exaclty the same results.

Im also displying the value of page and paged and Im always getting the same result:

```
echo 'Page: '.get_query_var('page');
echo 'Paged: '.get_query_var('paged');
```

Result:

Page: Paged: 0

This is really weird. Could you help me, please??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like your urls are rewritten by `mod_rewrite` and there is no variable `page[d]` anymore.. Can you post the output of `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` ?

Comment: According to wordpress API http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var get_query_var returns empty string if var is not set, Would that be helpfull?

Comment: hek2mgl thank you for the comment, the output is:
string(112) "/search/page/2/?location=0&type=0&bedrooms=empty&bathrooms=empty&minprice=empty&maxprice=empty&ref&submit=Search"